# MenuStrip in XNA 4.0

Tags: xna-4.0, windows-forms

Is it possible to place a MenuStrip into a XNA 4.0 project. This project is intended for PC-s only and I already have openFile dialogs, but I cant get the MenuStrip drawn. If this is not possible what would be a good alternative. I've been trying to get find it on create.msdn but it keeps redirecting me to the WinPhone/XBox selection page and I cant access the tutorials at all.

Comment: Is your game embedded in a WinForm or are you using a standard XNA project?

Comment: It is a XNA project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is to embed it in a proper WinForms container. Here are the current links to the WinForms samples, since MS *still* haven't fixed up the old links :(

- [WinForms Series 1: Graphics Device](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1)
- [WinForms Series 2: Content Loading](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_2)

Comment: Haha... yeah. When I was posting my answer I noticed my links were broken the first time around. -.-;

Answer (score 1):

Use the official sample, depending on what you want you may need more functionality. You can find more information at the link below. It includes a link to the PC template and sample.

http://code.google.com/p/xna-game-menu/